# How to reference a html template from a different directory in python flask

Tags: python, path, flask, directory

```
@app.route('/view', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def view_notifications():
    posts = get_notifications()
    return render_template("frontend/src/view_notifications.html", posts=posts)
```

So in my `project/backend/src/app.py` there's this code. How would I reference the template that's in `project/frontend/src/view_notifications.html` I've tried using `..` but it keeps saying the path isn't found. Is there another way I should be doing this?

```
[Tue Jun 23 12:56:02.597207 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 2736:tid 140166294406912] [remote 10.0.2.2:248] TemplateNotFound: frontend/src/view_notifications.html
[Tue Jun 23 12:56:05.508462 2015] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 2734:tid 140166614526016] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
```

Answer (score 77):

Flask is looking in `templates/frontend/src/view_notifications.html` for your template file. You either need to move your templates file to that location or change the default template folder.

According to the Flask docs you can specify a different folder for your templates. It defaults to `templates/` in the root of your app:

```
import os
from flask import Flask

template_dir = os.path.abspath('../../frontend/src')
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder=template_dir)
```

UPDATE:

After testing it myself on a Windows machine the templates folder does need to be named `templates`. This is the code I used:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template

template_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))))
template_dir = os.path.join(template_dir, 'frontend')
template_dir = os.path.join(template_dir, 'templates')
# hard coded absolute path for testing purposes
working = 'C:\Python34\pro\\frontend\\templates'
print(working == template_dir)
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder=template_dir)


@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

With this structure:

```
|-pro
  |- backend
    |- app.py
  |- frontend
    |- templates
      |- index.html
```

Changing any instance of `'templates'` to `'src'` and renaming the templates folder to `'src'` resulted in the same error OP received.

Comment: I added the template_folder argument and it's still saying template not found

Comment: Does it tell you what folder it's looking in?

Comment: Have you tried `project/frontend/src/view_notifications.html`?

Comment: Yes. It still gives me the same thing unfortunately.

Comment: What version of Flask are you using? If it is a version prior to 0.7 the `template_folder` keyword wasn't added. In that case you would have to put your templates in a `templates` directory at the root of your project.

Comment: IntelliJ is telling me the template can't be found before even running it.. so I'm not sure

Comment: Try using the absolute path to your `frontend/src` directory

Comment: unfortunately that won't work, because I'm uploading this to a vm that has different paths. Also other people will be working with the code and they will have different paths

Comment: Still get the same error. Template not found. Not really sure why

Comment: You may have to rename the src folder `templates`

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot! This worked really great and got me over the hump for using Flask! I really appreciate it! Note: Worked on Ubuntu 16.04 just fine :)

Answer (score 35):

A better solution is to just go directly without `os.path.abspath` like this:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='../../frontend/src')
```

Comment: In what way is using relative paths better? I'm not disagreeing but you should explain why in your answer.

Comment: because you can skip the os.path.abspath usage, within your presented solution you use relative path too and creates a absolute one based on that, but it works also without the conversion.

Comment: Right, it works but now if the file structure changes it requires a code change. You're trading maintainability/reliability for readability/ease. There is nothing wrong with that but it's not necessarily "better"; it's just different.

Comment: If the file structure changes, you need to adjust the code in your Solution as well. You are also using the same relativ path so my solution only adds readability but does not introduce additional maintenance overhead.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that Flask follows symlinks when searching for templates.

I put a symlink in the templates directory that points to my other template directory.

Comment: I wish I'd found this earlier. I found this same trick when trying to keep the code out of the public area, but getting the CSS / JS into the public area

Answer (score -1):

Flask will automatically detects folder name "templates". so you should create a folder called templates in project directory where your .py application file is present. Then place folder which contain html file inside templates folder. Hence your code will be

```
return render_template("frontend/src/view_notifications.html", posts=posts)
```

Ensure the path "frontend/src/view_notifications.html" is inside templates folder

Comment: That's not a valid answer. That flask uses a template folder is the problem and wants to be avoided.

Comment: Not a valid answer. The question is about looking for templates other than the default "templates" folder