# Flask project url path and folder path in projects page

Tags: python, flask

I am fairly new to flask and am trying to create a personal website as an exercise. I'm looking to build a project page, I wanted to ask the following questions regarding file and project url path:

1. I am trying to put all my project pages in the `/projects` folder. How do I `render_template` from a different folder so that `proj1()` function is pulling from `/projects/proj1.html` instead of `/tempates/.proj1.html`? Is there a better way of specifying a different folder location?
2. In `app.py`, I have `@app.route("/projects/project1")` hard-coded in for `proj1.html`. What is a better way to change this so that it can create a path for other projects like `proj2.html` and `proj3.html`? I believe I may need to write something like `@app.route("/projects/<project>")` and pass in the project name somehow?

Here is the folder structure:

```
/project
    app.py
    /templates
        home.html
        about.html
        layout.html
        proj1.html
        projects.html
    /projects
        proj1.html
        proj2.html
        proj3.html
```

My `app.py` looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
@app.route("/home")
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route("/projects/")
def projects():
    return render_template('projects.html', title='Projects')

@app.route("/projects/project1")
def proj1():
    return render_template('proj1.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Inside `projects.html` I have the following:

```
<h2><a href="project1">Project Link</a></h2>
```

Thank you! There's still a lot more work to be done, but I would set up the project page for now.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like better organization:

```
/project
    app.py
    /templates
        home.html
        about.html
        layout.html
        proj1.html
        projects.html
        /projects
            proj1.html
            proj2.html
            proj3.html
```

Then, use `return render_template('projects/proj1.html')`

That way all templates are in the `templates` directory, which is the default for Flask.  If you insist on using a separate dir, check the update on this answer: [How to reference a html template from a different directory in python flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31002890/how-to-reference-a-html-template-from-a-different-directory-in-python-flask/31003097)

Answer (score 0):

I also found this interesting answer: [How to dynamically select template directory to be used in flask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13598363/how-to-dynamically-select-template-directory-to-be-used-in-flask)

Check the answer form Ignas Butėnas is pretty interesting and he refers to the  jinja2.FileSystemLoader class, also explained in greater details here: [Jinja API](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/api/)

Also in the Flask Api Docs [Template folder](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/) it explains the following:

- template_folder – the folder that contains the templates that should be used by the application. Defaults to 'templates' folder in the root path of the application.