# Flask render_template not working to show a referenced template

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I'm new to python and Flask, and I'm trying to setup a basic page to render an HTML template. I followed the instructions/tutorials and I'm able to render HTML via the use of render_template like so:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
  return render_template(
    'index.html',
  )
```

I'm trying to now run a sample app, where the index.html in the app has actually a reference to another .html page, like so:

```
../../html/index.html
```

When I load this, I just see this text - literally. I assume it's trying to load the index.html from referenced folder (which I verified exists).

What is missing here? Am I missing a module or something?

**EDIT:**

This is where the main .py script is that I am running.

[image]

the `index.html` is in the `templates` directory. And then two folders up is the `html` folder that it seems to be referencing:

[image]

I know based on this, it should be "`../html/index.html`", but I've tried that, too and that doesn't work either.

Comment: Show us the template code and the project structure!

Comment: You likely need to  [`include`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22860144/4032503) you html file in the template, but without seeing your template code as @KlausD. asked for, it is hard to know for sure.

Comment: When you say template code, you mean what's in the index.html file?

Answer (score 0):

Static files in templates should be inserted using [url_for function](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.url_for) as described in Flask docs.
Your case would be:

```
url_for('../../html/index.html')
```

Comment: This did not work... now I just see the literal text `url_for('../../html/index.html')`

Comment: Have you seen [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31002890/how-to-reference-a-html-template-from-a-different-directory-in-python-flask/31003097)?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can do it in two ways `url_for('templates',filename='index.html')` where templates will be folder in which html files will be stored and
secondly you can use extend feature of jinja2 `{% extends index.html %}`